# Installing programs on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 just to get familiar with the environment but I can't install the softwares I use on windows. I need all the help I can get right now .

Comment: Related: http://www.linuxalt.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use a windows program (a .exe file) you can use Wine. follow these:

1. Go to Ubuntu Software Center, search for `wine` and install it.
2. Afterward by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> open the terminal.
3. Change direction with the command `cd Desktop`
4. Finally, run your program with this commad: `wine YourProgram.exe`

It will run your program. (I assumed that your exe file is on your Desktop, change the direction considering your exe file's real path.)

here you can find helpful things about Wine: [help.ubuntu.com/community/wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine)

but you will learn to find alternative programs for ubuntu very soon.

Comment: Please expand on your answer.  Rather than just posting a link, explaining how to use wine would be much better.  A quick Step by Step would be ideal.